# Binding an AppleScript to a button in OS X

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, finder, applescript, customization

I have asked a question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5267). But it is for adding a custom button in OS X Finder toolbar.

Suppose I have an AppleScript and I want to bind it on a custom button. And then I want to place that button on a toolbar - how that would be possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drag and drop an AppleScript (script and application) to the Finder toolbar, which places the icon for the AppleScript in the toolbar just like any other button (though I prefer the menu bar's AppleScript menu for such things because I can have more scripts available in a smaller space). I don't think you can create a button out of nothing and bind an AppleScript to it, however.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can’t add a custom button to the Finder directly to an Applescript, because the Finder’s toolbar is not an “Application Launcher”. It is, however, possible to create a small app (using Xcode) that does that. Out of my mind, you can check [ShellHere](http://etresoft.org/shellhere.html), which is a very simple application that puts a button in the Finder to “open a terminal here”.

The little app is Open Source, so you could see how he did it. It’s a very small project and if you have a little bit of Xcode/Cocoa experience, you’ll grasp the concept immediately.

Comment: You don't need XCode, do you? You can make an app in Automator that runs AppleScript, and place that in the Finder, I think.

Comment: @mankoff that’d be a good idea, haven’t tried that.